# CSS - How to set image max-height if screen is landscape and max-width if portrait?

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

I am attempting to create a basic, static webpage, with a header, image below that, and a few lines of text. Using an internet browser on a 1920x1080 monitor, the CSS rule `height: 70%;` works to make the image fill most of the screen while keeping the header and text visible without causing the page to scroll.

However, with this rule only, on my phone in portrait orientation, the image overflows to the right and causes a scroll bar to appear. The left side of the image starts 10 percent into the screen as specified by the `max-width: 80%;` body rule.

Below is my current stylesheet:

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}
img {
    height: 70%;
}
```

I have tried various combinations of `height`, `width`, `max-height`, and `max-width`, but I am unable to get the image to fill the entire page body the way I want. Specifically, on a landscape screen, I want the height to take precedence to make the image large without causing the page to scroll, and on portrait screens, I want the width to take precedence so that the image is as large as possible while leaving extra blank space at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by replacing `img` CSS rules with the following media rules:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    img {
        height: 70%;
    }
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine flex-box css with image ratio to do this

```css
 body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      div.container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      div.image {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
      }

      img {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <h1>Some title here</h1>
      <div class="image">
        <img
          alt="cover"
          src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1391498/pexels-photo-1391498.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
        />
      </div>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
      </p>
    </div>
```

Please view snippet as full page mode

Or play responsive with codepen: https://codepen.io/hi-b-i/pen/poEgKjp

Don't forget change view to left/right side